# How can I loop through column of df1 to see how often condition is met in df2?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1/1/2017', '4/1/2017', '7/1/2017', '10/1/2017', '1/1/2018']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Open Date': ['2/1/2017', '6/12/2017', '8/23/2017', '11/14/2017', '11/15/2017'], 
                    'Close Date': ['12/2/2017', '9/6/2017', '10/23/2017', '12/14/2017', '1/15/2018']})
```

My goal is to create a new column in `df1` which designates how many accounts were open on the exact date listed in df1. So in theory the output would look something like this:

```
Date      | Count
1/1/2017  |  0 Accounts open
4/1/2017  |  1
7/1/2017  |  2
10/1/2017 |  2
1/1/2018  |  1
```

This means individual accounts can be counted more than once because they could be active/open on more than one exact date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Open Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Open Date'])
df2['Close Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Close Date'])

>>> df1.assign(
    Accounts_open=df1['Date'].apply(
        lambda ts: (df2['Open Date'].le(ts) & df2['Close Date'].ge(ts)).sum()))
        Date  Accounts_open
0 2017-01-01              0
1 2017-04-01              1
2 2017-07-01              2
3 2017-10-01              2
4 2018-01-01              1
```